# Loading sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation, ssdt

Trying to load SQL Server and SSDT-BI from Visual Studio.  Got the below error when loading SQL Server 2014 and apparently it caused the Reporting Services-Native to fail to load.

[image]

I didn't take a screen shot of the actual error but the screen looked just like the second image except the file was in the `windows/temp` folder as stated on the below text.

```
Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Reporting Services
  Component error code:          0x84CF0003
  Error description:             Updating permission setting for folder 'C:\Windows\Temp' failed. The folder permission setting were supposed to be set to 'D:(A;OICI;0x1200af;;;S-1-5-80-425977601-1203083412-1631309457-2457533047-3321749933)'.
```

[image]

Do I have to get a 'succeeded' status for Report Services before I can load and use SSDT-BI/Visual Studio?  Suggestions on how to get Reporting Services to load successfully would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to retry the installation. If it fails, post the specific error messages out of the setup log. (It's in the location of your first screenshot.) Don't post the entire setup log - just post the specific lines involving the failure.

Comment: Should I uninstall the sql server 2014 first before retrying the installation?

Comment: No, just retry the portions that failed.

Comment: Try right-clicking the setup and selecting "run as administrator" instead of just double clicking it.

Comment: What is the operating system and the edition of SQL Server?

Comment: The operating system is Windows 7 Professional on a Levono Thinkpad and it is SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

BI Tools for SSDT is a standalone install meant for development and testing.

You can preview (render) SSRS reports within SSDT without having SSRS installed on your dev machine. This is for development only and will only be visible in SSDT. On a side note SSIS packages will function in the same manner. SSAS has no preview option - it requires a functional/full SSAS service available for deployment.

To deploy the reports you will obviously need a functional SSRS service running on the target server.

Answer (score 0):

> Component error code:          0x84CF0003
>     Error description:             Updating permission setting for folder 'C:\Windows\Temp' failed. The folder permission setting were supposed to be set to 'D:(A;OICI;0x1200af;;;S-1-5-80-425977601-1203083412-1631309457-2457533047-3321749933)'

I got similar error and posted a [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1616784/sql-server-2016-ctp2-0-reporting-services-failed-during-installation). I did this because this happened on my PC and I was the *only* admin on the machine. Unfortunately MS team was `unable to reproduce the scenario`

Below was reply given by MS team

> Could you verify your effective permissions on your C:\Windows\Temp
>   folder to make sure you are allowed "Change Permissions"?
>
> This can be done by following these steps:
>
> 1. Open Windows Explorer, and then locate the file or folder ("C:\Windows\Temp" in your case) for which you would like to view
>      effective permissions.
> 2. Right-click the file or folder, click Properties, and then click the Security tab.
> 3. Click Advanced, click the Effective Permissions tab, and then click "Select a user".
> 4. In "Enter the object name to select", enter the name of your user and then click OK.
> 5. Click "View effective access". The selected check boxes indicate the effective permissions of the user or group for that file or
>      folder.
>
> If you have a red "X" next to "Change Permissions", then take a look
>   at the "Access limited by" column to determine what is causing the
>   limited permission set. If you have a green check next to "Change
>   Permissions", then we'll have to look further to determine why you'd
>   be getting this error if you do have correct permissions for this
>   action.

Can you try the workaround mentioned.

Comment: The problem was solved by Levono Software Support who took off Avast anti-virus software, took off the malware protection program and another anti-worm/anti-virus program. Then the system could grant access to change the windows/temp folder and everything was fine after that. Thank you all to everyone who offered suggestions.